# RestSharp throws error in Entity Framework

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, c#-4.0, wcf-rest, restsharp

string URL="https://sampleservicebus.servicebus.windows.net/WinPhoneService/"

```
RestClient client = new RestClient(URL);
     RestRequest request = new RestRequest("getkpimeasuredata", Method.POST);
               KpiDomainData kpidata = new KpiDomainData();
               kpidata.KPIId = 1006;
               kpidata.ScorecardId = 3;
               kpidata.EngineeringOrgId = 11;
               kpidata.DataValuetypeId = 1;
               kpidata.CumulativeMonth = 463;
               kpidata.BusinessOrgId = 1;

               string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(kpidata);


               json = "{\"kpidata\" : " + json + "}";

               request.AddParameter("application/json; charset=utf-8", json, ParameterType.RequestBody);
               request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

               ObservableCollection<KpiMeasureData> kpiDetailsList = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync<ObservableCollection<KpiMeasureData>>(request);


               client.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
               {
                   if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                   {



                   }

               });
```

in the above call in the response im getting response.statuscode as ExpectationFailed
and response.Content is as follows

Actually my wcf service uses EF which will actual calls an SP which has dynamicsql to return the resultset..is this bcos of dynamic sql in SP.I have created functionImports and Complextype.**And the Restcall works when I use Webclient instead of Restclient**.But I need to use Restclient only...Please help...

```
   {"ErrorCode":"1001","ErrorMessage":"System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException: The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'ScaasModel.GetKPIMeasureData_Result'. A member of the type, 'ParamName', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.\u000d\u000a   at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.ColumnMapFactory.GetColumnMapsForType(DbDataReader storeDataReader, EdmType edmType, Dictionary`2 renameList)\u000d\u000a   at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.ColumnMapFactory.CreateColumnMapFromReaderAndType(DbDataReader storeDataReader, EdmType edmType, EntitySet entitySet, Dictionary`2 renameList)\u000d\u000a   at
```

Comment: actually when I debugged service code im able to see that all the values for KPIDomainData where sent as null to the method..eventhough im sending values.Please help

Comment: cAN someone help regarding this why the properties of KPIDomainData  where sent as null to service even im passing values